# Rails - Create order and order-rows with REST api

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just have a question regarding how to implement some logic.

Im building a API that allows the client to create orders.
This is solved by a OrderController#create so no problem!

Now, the issue is that an order can have many order-rows, all the relations are set correct but where should i create the order-rows in for the order?

Should the OrderController handle this or should i have a new controller that creates the order-rows for the particular order?

The clients post is sending the following json-data:

```
{
    "status": "paid",
    "total_sum": 20,
    "payment": "card",
    "order_rows": [
        {
            "id": 12,
        },
        {
            "id":13
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I ran into something similar with a project I'm working on now. The best (and long term simplest) solution was definitely to make a whole new model/controller.

```
*Order
    status (should be an int or enum probably)
    total (should loop through all order rows and total)
    payment (should be an int or enum probably)
    has_many order_rows

**OrderRow
    belongs_to Order
    item_sku
    item_name
    item_descr
    item_cost
    etc. etc.
```

This allows you to easily search for not just items, but orders that include items by name or sku, orders that include items by description. 
Your totals are dynamic.
You can retrieve total order numbers or movement numbers on a per item basis. 
It is so much easier to create and update orders.

The benefits go on.

It can easily be scoped;
scope :this_orders_rows, -> (order_id) {where(order_id: order_id)}

And it saves you from having to parse through hashes and arrays everytime.

To get technical about it, your order_controller should control ONLY your orders. If you start adding in a heap of other code to read through the arrays its going to get VERY cluttered. It's always better to move that to some other area.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It feels very reasonebla!